# How do i split in java script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a two dimensional array which consists of versions like,
say,

```
var version = [[B2.0.2.1],[B3.0.2.1], and many more];
```

How do I split B from these versions because I am only interested in the version that is 2.0.2.1 and so on?

Comment: You want to remove it completely?

Comment: What have you researched?  I assume these are strings (your code does not indicate that, but it seems they have to be strings).  There are lots and lots of string functions in Javascript listed [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String).  You should do a little research on your own and then try something and post here if you get stuck on what you tried and then post what you tried and why you got stuck.  Questions here should show basic effort first as we aren't just a code writing service.

Comment: that isn't valid javascript for a start

Answer (score 1):

The slice method will be useful in solving your problem.

Here is an example:

```
var str = "B2.0.2.1";
var res = str.slice(1); // Will result in second character until the end.
// res = "2.0.2.1"
```

If you use it with a single parameter `str.slice(1);` you will effectively cut off the first character leaving you with just the version number.. This is assuming that only one letter ever prefixes the versions numbers.

Comment: For an array of strings: `var removed = arr.map(function (x) { return x.slice(1); })`

Answer (score 0):

Use `array.map` to manipulate each element in array

```
var version = [['B2.0.2.1'],['B3.0.2.1']];
version = version.map(function(ver){
  return [ver[0].slice(1)];
});
```

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way, without loops is using JSON methods

```
var stripped = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(version).replace(/B/g, ''));
console.log(stripped);
```

In this case, I don't even care that your original code is invalid javascript, nor what you'd need to do to fix it, this will get rid of all B's regardless